# IPFS: base64-encoded image not showing as image

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipfs, js-ipfs

I have a simple function that tries to base64-encode an image and upload it to IPFS:

```
async function toIPFS() {
  const node = await IPFS.create()
  const data = fs.readFileSync('./src/assets/logo.png', 'base64').toString('base64')
  const results = await node.add(data)
  console.log(results.cid.string)
}
```

However, when I actually check [the hash](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmTstu2JNtz6R1UsgC828ryfXAyLDu4RF1ebHnh3BYto9C) it displays as a long string:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAYAAACtWK6eAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyNpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHB...etc
```

How do I upload an image such that it actually displays as an image? What am I missing?

I've never worked with images so pardon if this is a noob question:)

Comment: Where do you want to display the image?

Comment: Why are you base64 encoding it if you want to display it as an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing returned is the file encoded as base64, if you want to store  the image itself for later retrieval, this is how you'd do it:

```js
async function toIPFS() {
     const node = await IPFS.create()
     const data = fs.readFileSync('./src/assets/logo.png')
     const results = await node.add(data)
     console.log(results.cid.string)
}
```